# Reset list permissions for more than 20 thousand million records

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, csom

Below is the script that reset the permissions for the list items . it works fine when there are around 10 to 30 thousand items. However if the items are more than 2000000 million records the powershell script stuck and gives me th ebelow error. Can you please correct what i am doing wrong.

```
    function Restore-SPOListAllItemsInheritance
{

   param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [string]$Username,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
        [string]$Url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)]
        [string]$AdminPassword,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=4)]
        [string]$ListTitle
        )



   $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $AdminPassword -AsPlainText -Force
  $ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
  $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $password)
  $ctx.Load($ctx.Web.Lists)
  $ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
  $ctx.Load($ctx.Web.Webs)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  $list=$ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
  $ctx.Load($list)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

  #$spqQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery

  #$spqQuery.ViewXml ="<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>5000</RowLimit></View>";

## View XML
$qCommand = @"
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
    <Query>
        <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">5000</RowLimit>
</View>
"@
## Page Position
$position = $null

## All Items
$allItems = @()
Do{
    $camlQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $position
    $camlQuery.ViewXml = $qCommand
 ## Executing the query
    $currentCollection = $list.GetItems($camlQuery)
    $ctx.Load($currentCollection)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

 ## Getting the position of the previous page
    $position = $currentCollection.ListItemCollectionPosition

 # Adding current collection to the allItems collection
    $allItems += $currentCollection


}
# the position of the last page will be Null
Until($position -eq $null)

Write-Host $allItems.Count;
$c=0;
for($j=0;$j -lt $allItems.Count ;$j++)
  {
       $c++
      $allItems[$j].ResetRoleInheritance()
      $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
     Write-Host "Restored inherited permissions for the item: " $c
}

}
# Paths to SDK. Please verify location on your computer.
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

##Variables for Processing
Restore-SPOListAllItemsInheritance -Username "santoshkondapalli@micrososft.com" -Url "https://mysharepoint.santosh.com/sites/more" -AdminPassword "mytest1234#" -ListTitle "LossPreventionFiles"
```

Comment: no error reported in the question..

Comment: Sorry error thrown is Remote name could not be resolved & unable to read data